# Thread 1: signal 'SIGABRT' error message

Tags: ios

Have tried to compile and run this program, but have received this error message in the console:

```
2012-02-23 11:43:53.949 touches_v3[8667:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x6aab1e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key buttonShrink.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13bc052 0x154dd0a 0x13bbf11 0x9b3032 0x924f7b 0x924eeb 0x93fd60 0x23291a 0x13bde1a 0x1327821 0x23146e 0xd8e2c 0xd93a9 0xd95cb 0x39a73 0x39ce2 0x39ea8 0x40d9a 0x1f3b 0x119d6 0x128a6 0x21743 0x221f8 0x15aa9 0x12a6fa9 0x13901c5 0x12f5022 0x12f390a 0x12f2db4 0x12f2ccb 0x122a7 0x13a9b 0x1c42 0x1bb5)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

This doesn't make sense to me because while I did code "buttonShrink" as an object in the header file, I later deleted it, and deleted all references to it in the implementation file. There are no errors or warnings in either the header or implementation files.

Here is the code for those two.
Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIImageView *myIcon;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *myBackground;
    IBOutlet UIButton *shrinkButton;

    NSArray *bgImages;
    int currentBackground;
    bool hasMoved;
    bool hasShrunk;

    CGAffineTransform translate;
    CGAffineTransform size;
    UIButton *move;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain)UIImageView *myIcon; 
@property (nonatomic, retain)UIImageView *myBackground;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSArray *bgImages;
@property (nonatomic, retain)UIButton *shrinkButton;


- (IBAction)shrink:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)move:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)change:(id)sender;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myIcon, myBackground, bgImages, shrinkButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
hasMoved = NO;
    hasShrunk = NO;
    currentBackground = 0;

bgImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"wallPaper_01.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"wallPaper_02.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"wallPaper_03.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"wallPaper_04.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"wallPaper_05.png"],
             nil];


size = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.25, .25);
    translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -100);

myBackground.image = [bgImages objectAtIndex:currentBackground];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [myIcon release];
    [myBackground release];
    [shrinkButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([myIcon frame], [touch locationInView:nil]))
    {
        if(hasMoved == YES && hasShrunk == YES) {
            myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(size, 0, 0);
            hasMoved = 0;
        }
        if(hasMoved == YES && hasShrunk == NO) {
            myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
            hasMoved = NO;
        }

        myIcon.center = [touch locationInView:nil];
    }
}
- (IBAction)shrink:(id)sender {
    if (hasShrunk) {
        [shrinkButton setTitle:@"Shrink" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [shrinkButton setTitle:@"Grow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    if (hasShrunk == NO && hasMoved == NO) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = size;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasShrunk = YES;
    }

    else if (hasShrunk == NO && hasMoved == YES) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, .25, .25);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasShrunk = YES;
    }

    else if (hasShrunk == YES && hasMoved == YES) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, 1, 1);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasShrunk = YES;
    }

    if (hasShrunk == NO && hasMoved == NO) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasShrunk = YES;
    }

}

- (IBAction)move:(id)sender {

    if (hasMoved == NO && hasShrunk == NO) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = translate;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasMoved = YES;
    }

    else if (hasMoved == NO && hasShrunk == YES) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(size, 0, -100);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasMoved = YES;
    }

    else if (hasMoved == YES && hasShrunk == YES) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(size, 0, 0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasMoved = YES;
    }

    if (hasMoved == NO && hasShrunk == NO) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        myIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        hasMoved = YES;
    }

}

- (IBAction)change:(id)sender {
    currentBackground++;
    if (currentBackground >=[bgImages count])
    currentBackground = 0;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"changeView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    if (currentBackground == 1) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
    }

    if (currentBackground == 2) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];
    }

    if (currentBackground == 3) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
    }

    if (currentBackground == 4) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    myBackground.image = [bgImages objectAtIndex:currentBackground];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a button in InterfaceBuider that is linked to an action called "buttonShrink". Looks like you probably renamed the method in your class, but did not update the association in InterfaceBuilder.

Comment: Yes, found the problem. I had a dangling outlet. Once I deleted that, it compiled fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a reference to buttonShrink in your nib files. Look in IB. You can grep the `.xib` files if you're not certain where it might be.

Comment: I have a button called "shrinkButton" but no visible "buttonShrink". How do I grep for "buttonShrink" in the .xib file?